# Prove that $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(b, a-b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I can understand the concept that $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(b, r)$, where $a = bq + r$, which is grounded from the fact that $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(b, a-b)$, but I have no intuition for the latter.

Answer (score 6):

Let $d = \text{gcd}(a,b)$, then $d|a$, and $d|b$, so $d|(a-b)$, and $d|\mbox {gcd}(b,a-b)= d'$. Also $d'|b$, and $d'|(a-b)$, so $d'|(b+(a-b)) = a$, and $d'|\mbox {gcd}(a,b) = d$. So $d = d'$.

Comment: How do you prove that $$d \mid gcd(b, a-b)=d'$$

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma:** $gcd(x,y)=d$ iff $d$ is the smallest natural number that can be expressed as a linear combination of $x$ and $y$ (in $\mathbb{Z}$)

We have $gcd(a,b)=d$

$d=ap+bq$ for some $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$

$d=ap-bp+bp+bq=(a-b)p+b(p+q)=(a-b)p+bq'$

where $q'=p+q\in \mathbb{Z}$

Thus,

$gcd(a-b,b)=d$

Comment: That lemma is only true in the forward direction. For example, $1\cdot5+1\cdot4=9$ but $\gcd(5,4)=1\neq9$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Would the converse be true if the condition of d being the smallest such positive natural number is added?

Comment: yes, it would. The $\gcd$ of $x,y$ is the smallest positive natural number that can be expressed as an integral linear combination of $x,y$.

Comment: Edited, thank you! @Harry

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\gcd(a, b) = q$ it means at least that $q | a, q|b$ then $q|(a - b)$. This is true for every divisor so that for $\gcd$ also.

One user asked converse but it is also obvious. Denote $s = a - b$, then $\gcd(b, s) = \gcd(b, s + b) = \gcd(b, a)$.

Comment: You need to prove also the converse, if $q'|b$ and $q'|a-b$ then $q'|a$, but +1 anyway.

Comment: It's just that your first statement only proved that $gcd(a,b)|gcd(b,a-b)$, not equality. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

By definition
$$gcd(a,b)=g\iff g|a,b\land (\forall h:h|a,b\implies h\le g).$$

Then

$$\begin{align}gcd(a,b)=g&\implies g|a,b\land (\forall h:h|a,b\implies h\le g)\\&\implies g|b,(a-b)\land (\forall h:h|b,(a-b)\implies h|a,b\implies h\le g)\\&\implies gcd(b,a-b)=g.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Every common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is also a common divisor of $b$ and $a-b$.

Every common divisor of $b$ and $a-b$ is also a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, as $a=(a-b)+b$.

Comment: This answer moves the problem from $gcd$ to divisors. $d$ divides $a$ and $b$ implies $d$ divides $a\pm b$ is a rather trivial property. ($a=md,b=nd\implies a\pm b=(m\pm n)d$.)

Answer (score 0):

$d\mid a-b$ means $\dfrac{a-b}d=\dfrac ad-\dfrac bd$ is an integer. It's clear that if one of these fractions is an integer, then so is the other, i.e., $d\mid a\iff d\mid b$.

$d\mid\gcd(b,a-b)\implies d\mid b$, thus $d\mid a$.

Therefore a divisor of both $a-b$ and $b$ is also a divisor of $a$.

Conversely, $k\mid a$ means $\dfrac ak=\dfrac{a-b}k+\dfrac bk$ is an integer, so $k\mid a-b\iff k\mid b$.

$k\mid\gcd(a,b)\implies k\mid b$, thus $k\mid a-b$.

Therefore a divisor of both $a$ and $b$ is also a divisor of $a-b$. QED

Answer (score 0):

Write $u=b$ and $v=a-b$. Then $a=u+v$ and $b=u$.

These two sets of equations imply that $d$ divides $u,v$ iff $d$ divides $a,b$. Therefore, $\gcd(u,v)=\gcd(a,b)$.

In algebra terms, the equations imply that $\{a,b\}$ and $\{u,v\}$ generate the same subgroup of $\mathbb Z$. It's well known that $\langle x,y \rangle = \gcd(x,y)\mathbb Z$, hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about "greatest": let's simply look at *the set of common divisors*.

The set $\mathrm{CD}(a,b)$ of common divisors of $a$ and $b$ is by definition
$$
\mathrm{CD}(a,b) = \{ d \in \mathbb{Z} \colon d \text{ divides } a \text{ and } d \text{ divides } b \}.
$$

And similarly, the set $\mathrm{CD}(b,a-b)$ of common divisors of $a$ and $a-b$ is by definition
$$
\mathrm{CD}(b,a-b) = \{ d \in \mathbb{Z} \colon d \text{ divides } b \text{ and } d \text{ divides } a-b \}.
$$

In fact, we have $$\mathrm{CD}(a,b)=\mathrm{CD}(b,a-b)$$ so obviously they have the same "greatest" element (i.e., $\max\mathrm{CD}(a,b)=\max\mathrm{CD}(b,a-b)$).

To prove this, we check...

- If $x \in \mathrm{CD}(a,b)$, then $x$ divides both $b$ and $a-b$, so $x \in \mathrm{CD}(b,a-b)$.

  *Proof*: By definition $x$ divides $b$.  Further, we know $x$ divides both $a$ and $b$, so $a=kx$ and $b=k'x$ for some integers $k$ and $k'$.  Thus $x$ divides $(k-k')x=a-b$.
- If $y \in \mathrm{CD}(b,a-b)$, then $y$ divides both $a$ and $b$, so $y \in \mathrm{CD}(a,b)$.

  *Proof*: By definition $y$ divides $b$.  Further, we know $y$ divides both $b$ and $a-b$, so $b=cy$ and $a-b=c'y$ for some integers $c$ and $c'$.  Thus $y$ divides $(c-c')y=b+(a-b)=a$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Answer (score -2):

First of all,

- ***definition:*** $b|a \iff \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}: a = k \cdot b$
- ***Lemma 1:*** $a|b \wedge a|b \Rightarrow a = \pm b$
- ***Lemma 2:*** $d|a \wedge d|b \Rightarrow d|(ax + by)$, for any $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$
- ***Theorem 1:*** If a and b are any integers, not both zero, then $gcd(a,b)$ is the smallest positive element of the set $\{ax + by: x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ of linear combinations of a and b.

Thus, we need to prove $gcd(,)|gcd(,−)$ and $gcd(,−)|gcd(,)$, and as $gcd$ is always positive, they must be equal by ***Lemma 1***.

## 1. $gcd(,)|gcd(,−)$

Let $d = gcd(,)$, thus $d|a \wedge d|b$ and, also, $d|(a-b)$ as it is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$ (***Lemma 2***).

$d|b$, $d|(a-b)$, and $gcd(,−)$ is a linear combination of $b$ and $a-b$ (***Theorem 1***). Therefore, $d|gcd(,−)$ by ***Lemma 2***.

## 2. $gcd(,−)|gcd(,)$

Let $d = gcd(,−)$, thus $d|b \wedge d|(a-b)$.

$a = b + (a - b)$, thus $a$ is a linear combination of $b$ and $a - b$.

Therefore, $d|a$ by ***Lemma 2***.

Again, $gcd(a,b)$ is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$ by ***Theorem 1***, thus $d|gcd(a,b)$.

### Finally, using ***Lemma 1***:

$gcd(,)|gcd(,−) \wedge gcd(,−)|gcd(,) \Rightarrow gcd(,) = gcd(,−)$

> Note that if $a = b = 0$, then $gcd(a,b) = gcd(b, a - b) = gcd(0,0) = 0$ by definition.

### Proof of ***lemma 1***

By ***definition***, $b|a \Rightarrow |b| \leq |a|$. Therefore, $a|b \wedge b|a \Rightarrow |a| = |b| \Rightarrow a = \pm b$.

### Proof of ***lemma 2***

As $d|a \wedge d|b$, there are some integers $k_1$ and $k_2$ which meets $\frac{a}{d} = k_1$ and $\frac{b}{d} = k_2$.

Now, we need to prove $(ax + by) = k \cdot d$, for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$(ax + by) = k \cdot d \iff k = \frac{a}{d}x + \frac{b}{d}y = k_1x + k_2y$

As the multiplication of two integers is an integer, and this also follows for the sum of two integers, thus $k_1x + k_2y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

### Proof of ***Theorem 1***

This is proved at: Cormen, T.H., Leiserson, C.E., Rivest, R.L., Stein, C., Introduction to algorithms, MIT Press, 3a.
ed., 2009.

page 930, Theorem 31.2.